# Hiding multiple axis highstock, fill empty space

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I'm building a demo chart with highstock displaying 4 axis, two on each side http://jsbin.com/oyicuc/3/edit

I'd like the axis to hide when you click on the series in the legend and for the chart to fill the remaining space. I've used the showempty: false property on the y axis, this works on the outer axis but if you hide the inner axis then the gap where it was remains.

Anybody know if this can be done?  Thanks in advance

Comment: This is known issue: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/705

Comment: Is this definitely the same problem? I'm not sure how the workaround could work for this?

Comment: Yes it is related with known bug.

Comment: You have to reset extremes as in my example: 

          `chart.xAxis[flip].min = null;
      chart.xAxis[flip].max = null;
      chart.xAxis[flip].hasVisibleSeries = false;
     
      chart.xAxis[flip].setExtremes(null, null);`